# Rewrite formula for transformation about point other the Origo in xy-plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, rotations

This may seem like a simple question, but I can't wrap my head around it, and I haven't been able find the answer on the web.

The formula for rotating a point, defined by the vector $\vec{x}$, around another point, defined by the vector  $\vec{x_0}$, with an angle, $\theta$, given by the rotation matrix, $A_\theta$, is:

$D(\vec{x}) = A_\theta(\vec{x}-\vec{x_0}) + \vec{x_0}$

I get the logic behind this, but now I am to proof that the expression above is the same as:

$D(\vec{x}) = A_\theta\vec{x} + (I_2 - A_\theta)\vec{x_0}$

Can some of you tell me how I get from the first expression to the second expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Any matrix is a linear operator, meaning $M(x+y)=Mx+My$, where $M$ is a matrix and $x,y$ are vectors. Also $I_2$ is the notation for the identity matrix.

Comment: Don't overthink it, this is basic algebra. You're asking why $a(x-y)+y = ax + (1-a)y$.